# head_option.phtml, i commented google.api call fonts, but there is script file in that . is it okey to remove the script

Tags: magento2.3.1

var ThemeOptions = {
        box_wide: getConfig('general_section/layout/box_wide') ?>,
        rtl_layout: getConfig('general_section/layout/enable_rtl') ?>,
        sticky_header: getConfig('general_section/header/sticky_header') ?>       
    }; 
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod|iPhone Simulator|iPod Simulator/i) !== null){
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
            document.body.classList.add('iMenu');
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

It's not okay to remove that script, it can cause the menu not to work as expected due to that script adding **iMenu** class to the body class.

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as **accepted**. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.